# Random Arrays allowed in Java Syntax?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

I'm a bit dumbfounded:

I was writing a little bit of code for my application, and I made a typo. I added square brackets, instead of the p. Smart Eclipse added the other bracket for me. To my surprise, no warning popped up, about any syntax errors.

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");[]
// No Warnings or Errors?!?!?
this.initalize();
```

I can add them anywhere in constructors and methods, but no where outside of that. I continued experimenting:

```
this.initalize();[][][]
// this.parent.setJMenuBar(this); 
this.setVisible(true);
```

I can have multiple arrays...

```
this.initalize();[[]] // Syntax Error, delete this token
//this.parent.setJMenuBar(this); 
this.setVisible(true);
```

But nothing nested.

I tried a little more... I get errors in certain places.

```
JMenuItem help_about = new JMenuItem("About the Developers...");
[] // Error!
help_help.setToolTipText("Access the help center");
```

Semi-colons make these error-prone:

```
[]; // Error!
```

It seems as if I can put these brackets anywhere as long as there is a reserved keyword that follows...

```
[]
return view; // No Errors here...
```

Nothing changes as I save the code, restart Eclipse or anything. A little information about my system:

- Eclipse Luna 4.4.2
- Compliance Level 1.6
- Java 7 (I think) Nope! Java Version 1.6.0_65

So, here's my question...

- Is this a bug with eclipse?
- Is this something unintended with java syntax?
- Or, is it...

## It's not a bug... It's a Feature!!!

Comment: Maybe your Eclipse didn't refresh? I tried duplicating your "non-errors" but I got syntax highlighting and errors. Sometimes, Eclipse just doesn't show error highlighting right away because it hasn't parsed your code for some reason. So, I'd say, it's just Eclipse taking too long, or freezing up. It's not really a bug, but a common occurrence. Maybe try closing and reopening Eclipse.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that right now...

Comment: Have you tried compiling outside of Eclipse using `javac` and the command prompt?  But yeah, it would be cool if Jay Gosling created Java with hidden features, kind of like the minus world in the original Super Mario Brothers Nintendo game.

Comment: I am using java8 and it is giving me error in very first attempt. What do you mean by `Java 7 (I think)`. you don't know what version you are using?

Comment: This is a bug in your Eclipse or you're misreading what Eclipse is showing you. This is not valid syntax. It never was.

Comment: @afzalex I feel really really really stupid asking this, but how do you figure that out... :P

Comment: You can know about java version at runtime by using code : `System.getProperty("java.version");` Or you can check the version by cmd `java -version`

Answer (score 0):

It is neither a bug of eclipse nor it is a feature provided by java.
I ran the same code in Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and with java 7 and it give me error.
As it is commented by Sotirios it is not a valid syntax.
On the other hand if you have written `;` or `{}` in the same way you are using `[]`, they will not give you error. But it is because java compiler understand it and they are valid.

So you might be not getting error may be due to some other reasons like may be eclipse have not compiled your code when you saw it error free or may be it is taking too much time for some reason etc.

Comment: Adding a semi-colon after the brackets gives the error straight away, and don't braces denounce a code-block? Semi-colons finish statement, which can be empty. Not the same thing it looks...

Comment: No, using semi-colon will not give error (until it is changing syntax of some other statements) and yes, we should not use `{}` this way but The point is they will not give error.

Comment: But the comparison is not valid. It's already known. What do the square brackets denounce? Why is this happening?

Comment: That's fine. But why is the square brackets valid? Since semi-colons make the end of a statement, and brackets make a code block, the comparison of valid syntax to square brackets isn't there.

Comment: Actually `;` are delimiter in java like space in english and we can use more than 1 space but its meaning will not change. And `{}` give a scoped block, which java will read but will not found anything inside, but that doesn't make it erroneous.

Comment: As this doesn't tell me a concrete answer for the actions that I have detailed. -1

Comment: Let's not sugar coat it, this *is* a bug in OP's Eclipse.

Comment: @bayou.io It cannot be. OP's Eclipse is not different than the Eclipse used by other people of same version (And of luna). And it is java compiler which will be responsible for giving error and jvm for executing that program. I am sure even in OP's Eclipse he cannot run the program even by adding single invalide `[]`.